# Cloudinary conflict with scss django

Tags: django, sass, cloudinary

I'm having a Django Project and a problem setting up Cloudinary storage along with the SCSS preprocessor. First of all the preprocessor works well and compiles the files. But when I add:
`STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'cloudinary_storage.storage.StaticHashedCloudinaryStorage'`
I get the error:
`TypeError: MediaCloudinaryStorage.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ROOT'`

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'sass_processor.finders.CssFinder',
]
```

If I comment out STATICFILES_FINDERS, I get a different error:
`ValueError: Couldn't load manifest 'staticfiles.json' (version 1.0)`

If I'm trying to upgrade cloudinary_storage, I'm receiving:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cloudinary_storage (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cloudinary_storage
```

Please advise how to properly configure Cloudinary and SCSS so that they do not conflict

Please advise how to properly configure Cloudinary and SCSS so that they do not conflict

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every other detail is right with your code, To move your static files to Cloudinary, update your settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'cloudinary_storage.storage.StaticHashedCloudinaryStorage'
```

And run `python manage.py collectstatic`

Please note that only files with hashed name will be uploaded by default - this behavior can be changed by adding `--upload-unhashed-files` argument to `collectstatic` command. If you are not sure why it is useful to add hash to file names, shortly speaking, it allows static files to be safely cached by Cloudinary CDN and web browsers. Without it files' modification would become very problematic, because your website's users would use their private older copies. Hashing prevents this issue as any file change will change its url as well, which would force a browser to download a new version of a file.

Visit https://pypi.org/project/django-cloudinary-storage/ for more information.

Comment: I already had it in the settings. In addition, when I run the python manage.py collectstatic command, I get the same error:
"C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 81, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: MediaCloudinaryStorage.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ROOT'

Comment: Are you using the latest version of cloudinary 1.37.0? Also what's your Django version?

Comment: I am using cloudinary==1.36.0 and Django==4.1. Previously I was using Django==4.2.6 but had an error "raise NotSupportedError(
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: PostgreSQL 12 or later is required (found 11.18)."
So decided to downgrade version